# Sequelize query return wrong response

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I use sequelize with MySQL,

if I run this query :

```
        FROM                stades
        WHERE               stades.id NOT IN  (SELECT       DISTINCT reservations.stade_id as stade_id
                                               FROM                 reservations
                                               WHERE                reservations.from >= '2021-08-01 09:00:00'
                                               AND              reservations.to <= '2021-08-01 10:00:00'
                                               AND                  reservations.business_id = 1)
```

in Sequel pro it returns the correct response,

but when I run it throw sequelize it returns a wrong response

Comment: Are you running the query as it is in sequelize or are you using the ORM methods of sequelize?

Comment: @Ikdemm nop i'm not using ORM  (sequelize.query( 'SELECT ...)